# How to add minutes to specific row in R?

Tags: r, time

I have a dataframe like below

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(time = c("12:21", "12:22", "12:45"
), MIN = c(7, 41, 147)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(943L, 
946L, 947L))
```

I have to add time and MIN columns.Tried like below.

```
library(data.table)
d1$MIN <- as.ITime(paste0("00:",d1$MIN*60*60,":00") ### because 147 mins is 2hrs :27 mins

d1$time1 <- d1$time + d1$MIN
```

The `MIN` column getting `NA` after conversion. I want to convert only 147mins to `02:27:00`. But I can't convert only that particular value as `as.ITime(d1$MIN*60*60)` becauase whole column should have only one data type. How to convert only that value in a column as `02:27:00`.

Comment: Add all non `base` packages to the question please.

Comment: I have used ```data.table``` package.

Comment: You write *because 147 mins is 2hrs :45 mins* Why? Isn't it 2hrs 27mins??? And is the goal to add the `MIN` column to the `time` column?

Comment: Yes, it's ```2hrs: 27 mins``` .It's type mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we convert `time` to a proper datetime type we can then just add seconds. I.e.:

```
d1 <- structure(list(time = c("12:21", "12:22", "12:45"),
                     MIN = c(7, 41, 147)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(943L, 946L, 947L))
```

Convert the `time` column to POSIX using `strptime`:

```
d1$time <- strptime(d1$time, format="%H:%M")
```

Add seconds:

```
d1$time1 <- d1$time + d1$MIN * 60
```

`d1` is now:

```
d1


                   time MIN               time1
943 2020-03-16 12:21:00   7 2020-03-16 12:28:00
946 2020-03-16 12:22:00  41 2020-03-16 13:03:00
947 2020-03-16 12:45:00 147 2020-03-16 15:12:00
```

If we want to show only the time part of `time1` (or time2) we can use `format(df$time1, format = "%H:%M")`, but we should only do this for printing purposes and leave the column internally as datetime (for example: what happens if we add 23hrs?)